# custom url in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-rewriting

I have controller called 'project' with method of index

I want to pass project_id 
it works with this url:
 URL: `http://example.com/project/index/project_id`

what I am trying to do is to have url for each project 
`http://example.com/project_id`
for example: 
`http://example.com/rickyboby`

I tried this code 
`$route['(:any)'] = "project/index/$1";`
It worked I could access project_id from url www.example.com/project_id but the problem is I have other controllers are not working now, for example I have welcome controller, the url: www.example.com/welcome/ is routing me to project page, how can I solve that ?

Comment: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

Comment: Read about RESTful routing.

Comment: Can achieve this by routing

Comment: I tried this code `$route['(:any)'] = "project/index/$1";` It worked I could access project_id from url www.example.com/project_id but the problem is I have other controllers are not working now, for example I have welcome/ controller, the url: www.example.com/welcome/ is routing me to project page, how can I solve that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to whitelist all the controllers you have before the "any" rule because they go in order (so in your example, `/welcome` would take you to `project/index/welcome`). For example:

```
$route['welcome'] = "welcome";
$route['somethingElse'] = "someOtherUrl";
$route['(:any)'] = "project/index/$1";
```

You can also try to think of a clever way of doing this with regex, but I think you're better off with a whitelist.

---

This is a basic programming concept and probably doesn't belong here, but you can always do something like:

```
$controllers = array('welcome', 'otherController', 'etc');
foreach($controllers as $c) {
    $route[$c] = $c; // make all URLs from the list go to their same-named controllers
}
$route['(:any)'] = "project/index/$1"; // handle the other URLs
```

---

One more thing - don't forget to prevent users from giving projects names that match existing controller names (such as `welcome`) because their project won't be accessible! There, yet another reason to have that controller list someplace...

Comment: There is no way to detect if the string after url is match the an exist controller name if so we show it else  routes to my project controller ?

Comment: That's what my answer is about - you need a list of controllers (called a whitelist) and first check if it's one of them, if not - go to the project controller. How would you get the list of all controllers?

Comment: Is there a function or way to get a list of all my controllers, I don't like to hard code them.

Comment: I'm not sure there is one... it might be worth checking the docs. But I gave you a super-simple example with an array. Not sure it could get any easier than that especially since `project` is also a controller and you'd still need to find a way to tell the app to skip it.

Comment: I wanna do something like: $controllers = get_my_controllers(); It shouldn't be difficult, thanks, I will look for it

Comment: Yeah, yeah, I understand what you want to do, I just don't think there is a simple way.

Comment: very interesting thing to follow up. @Shomz https://github.com/pprins/CI_ListControllers is a quite decent solution to get controller names dynamically.

Comment: @karanthakkar Nice find. This thing parses the controllers directory and creates a list.

Comment: @Shomz yup so we can avoid hard coding the array. but as you pointed out if any project name has similar name to controller there will be an issue. +1 for such observation.

Comment: @karanthakkar Yes, OP needs to be super-careful with that stuff, especially if he decided to write/rename a few controllers at a later stage and there turns out to be a project with that name.

Answer (score 0):

Place the "welcome" routing rule before the "project" routing rule. This way the system will match welcome and won't go looking for the next rule. Alternatively, you could use (:num) instead of (:any), this way it will match only numbers (in case your project ids are numbers).

Comment: My project Id is a string, Should I for every controller I have to add a route for it ? There is no way to detect if the string after url is match the controller name to show it else it routes to my project controller ?